# Add rows to WPF DataGrid when bound to EF Entities (do "UserCanAddRows" programmatically)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

The DataGrid has a feature called "UserCanAddRows" which provides the user an empty row he can use for adding a new row to the DataGrid. However, I want to provide my users an extra control to add new rows as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

But now the problems raise. I have my DataGrid bound to an ObjectSet of the Microsoft Entity Framework. When adding an item to the ObjectSet, it won't appear there unless I do save the changes to the Database. Therefore the addedObject is saved to some extra list which holds all "pending changes". However, my DataGrid is not aware of this "pending changes or ObjectStateList" when I add them programmatically. So, they don't show up in the DataGrid, also not after refreshing the View.

**BUT, the DataGrid is aware of them, when the "UserCanAddRows"-Feature is used! So, all I want to do is tp use this feature programmatically or imitate the things that feature does.**

Now, my relevant code:

```
        private readonly MyEntities m_db;
        private CollectionViewSource m_workItemViewSource;
        private ObjectSet<WorkItem> m_workItems;

        public SettingsWindow(MyEntities db)
        {
            m_db = db;
            InitializeComponent(); 
            m_workItemViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("workItemViewSource")));

        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_workItems = m_db.WorkItems;
            m_workItemViewSource.Source = m_workItems;
        }

       private void AddWorkItemButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkItem workItem = m_db.CreateObject<WorkItem>();
            workItem.name = AddWorkItemTextBox.Text;
            workItem.is_shown = true;
            AddWorkItemTextBox.Text = "";
            m_workItems.AddObject(workItem);
            m_workItemViewSource.View.Refresh();
        }
```

Here the XAML

```
  <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="workItemViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:WorkItem, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>

   <DockPanel Name="WindowDockPanel"  LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{StaticResource workItemViewSource}">

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="workItemDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Width="280" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="is_shownColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=is_shown, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="{x:Static Resources:EntityStrings.isShown}" Width="SizeToHeader" >
      </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="{x:Static Resources:EntityStrings.workItem}" Width="*" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>  
    </DataGrid>  

  </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already moved on and implemented it a different way. But I gained some experience now. What I learned is, that the collections from the EF context (m_db in my case) don't implement the INotifyChange interface. Nor do they hold new added entries in their lists. I had this problem again at a different place and fixed it "right" this time:

The key is not to use the collections given by the context. It doesn't harm, if you put them in a different collection like ObservableCollection. So it should work with this changes, however I cant test it anymore:

```
    private readonly MyEntities m_db;
    private CollectionViewSource m_workItemViewSource;
    private ObserverableCollection<WorkItem> m_workItems; //changed!
    public SettingsWindow(MyEntities db)
    {
        m_db = db;
        InitializeComponent(); 
        m_workItemViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("workItemViewSource")));

    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_workItems = new ObservableCollection( m_db.WorkItems ); //changed!
        m_workItemViewSource.Source = m_workItems;
    }

   private void AddWorkItemButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkItem workItem = m_db.CreateObject<WorkItem>();
        workItem.name = AddWorkItemTextBox.Text;
        workItem.is_shown = true;
        AddWorkItemTextBox.Text = "";
        m_workItems.AddObject(workItem);
        m_workItemViewSource.View.Refresh();
    }
```